# Need help understanding and solving some algebra equations involving massive numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am having some trouble understanding how to go about solving questions that involve extremely large numbers ( at least in the sense of something you write on paper).

Now I understand there must be some tricks and such, or else it wouldnt be feasible.

Please keep in mind I am wanting to solve these without any use of a calculator or computer etc, strictly by hand. PS: These are not from any assignment, they are from past midterms found on Google from the early 2000s, I am using them to practice for my exam.

Ill give two examples, and my thoughts and such.

Example 1:

Find the GCD of $$a = 13200000008150000000000000000132$$ and
$$b = 1320000000815$$.

My thoughts: I thought that if we notice there are the same amount of zeros between the 132 and 815 on both,

so maybe I could write

$a=b(10^{20})+132$ for example

and then

$b=132(10^7)+815$ for example,

then I get to $132(10^7)=(815)(x)+(y)$

and I am not sure how to proceed.

(Answer given by wolfram is 1)

and for example 2:

Compute the least residue modulo $N = 95$ of the integer

$3^{11000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}$

My thoughts are to use some sort of Fermat little thereom approach,

For example I know that $3^{11}=3mod(11)$

and I also know $3^{10}=1mod11$

so I could multiply $3^{10}$ many times to get the zeros, and then im stuck.

And lastly, one I am completely lost on is

calculate a for $x=a mod N$

for $$7^{13198459348751983475867345892342398209234983465234531}$$

in Mod 11, 55 and 5,

my only thoughts were along the lines of for 11, we could have 11000....000000

leaving 2198........... etc

but I am truly just not sure.

I am interested in any insight,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n>m$, then $\gcd(n,m)=\gcd(m,n\pmod{m})$, hence:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}&\phantom{}&\gcd(13200000008150000000000000000132,1320000000815)\\&=&\gcd(1320000000815,132)\\&=&\gcd(815,312)\\&=&\gcd(5\cdot 163,2^3\cdot 3\cdot 13)=\color{red}{1}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

---

About the second exercise, we know that $95=5\cdot 19$, hence in order to find
$$ 3^{11\cdot 10^{42}}\pmod{95} $$
we just need to find the residue classes modulo $5$ and $19$. By the Fermat's little theorem, $3^{4k}\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, hence the residue class modulo $5$ is one. On the other hand, $11\cdot 10^{42}$ is even and congruent to $11$ modulo $9$, hence $11\cdot 10^{42}$ is congruent to $2\pmod{18}$ and 
$$ 3^{11\cdot 10^{42}}\equiv 3^{2}\equiv 9\pmod{19},$$
hence
$$ 3^{11\cdot 10^{42}}\equiv \color{red}{66}\pmod{95} $$
by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Thanks , that makes sense. Do you have any insight on the second example>

Comment: @Quality: insights about the second exercise added.

Answer (score 3):

This practically screams for Euclid's algorithm to be used. It gives us the following:
$$
\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a-b\cdot 10^{19}, b)
$$
where you can notice that $c = a-b\cdot 10^{19} = 132$ (I think that's the right power of $10$...) Continuing, we get
$$
\gcd(c, b) = \gcd(c, b-c\cdot 10^{10})
$$
where $d = b-c\cdot 10^{10} = 815$ (again, the exponent might be a bit off). This means we've reduced the whole problem to
$$
\gcd(132, 815)
$$
Can you take it from here?